# Passing data to Rest API

Tags: python-3.x, api, flask, rest

i'm a newbie to Rest API's. i have been trying to create a api which takes input from users process it and send the output. basically, i have a file grades.py which predicts the grades of students using ML. and i have another file server.py with flask . and api code in server.py is '

```
@app.route('/Api/score/id',methods=['GET','POST']) 
def getscore(score_id):
    score_id=request.args['score_id']
    return grades.predictor(score_id)
'
```

and i'm invoking the api with 
'`http://localhost:5000/Api/score/id?/score_id=1`'
in postman.
I'm getting the error

> '`TypeError: getscore() missing 1 required positional argument: 'score_id'` '

can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the paramater score_id from the function

```
@app.route('/Api/score/id',methods=['GET','POST']) 
def getscore():
    score_id=request.args['score_id']
    return grades.predictor(score_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@app.route('/Api/score/id/<score_id>', methods=['GET','POST']) 
def getscore(score_id):
  return grades.predictor(score_id)
```

Try to call your route with `http://localhost:5000/Api/score/id/1`. This should work.